# Box Blur Challenge

Tags: fastest-code

The challenge is to implement a box blur in any language. The input will be as a 32-bit uncompressed bitmap, BGRA, preceded by one byte defining the radius of the blur and one byte defining the width of the image. The output should be in the same format as the input (minus the blur radius, of course).

Fastest code wins, and a 50-point bounty to the shortest entry, and another to the "most obfuscated" in my opinion.

Comment: Is this 1 dimensional or 2 dimensional?  if 2, how do we determine the image dimensions?

Comment: 8-bits per channel? Blur is crappy linear averaging rather than taking gamma into account?

Comment: Challenge is way too vague as it stands - at the very least you need to specify the blur algorithm much more precisely

Comment: @Paul R: No particular algorithm in mind, as long as it blurs. Sorry, I should have specified that. @Keith Randall: By "bitmap" I meant "bitmap image, 2-dimensional". And yes, blur is "crappy averaging", @Peter Taylor.

Comment: @Keith Randall: The input will end in EOF in the language of your choice.

Comment: @minitech: if the image is 2-D, then we'll need to know the X and Y dimensions, not just the total size (X*Y) which we can get from the input size.

Comment: @Keith Randall: Fixed.

Comment: @Joey: for greyscale yes, but for RGBA there is more than one way of applying a box blur

Comment: Is the input a _bitmap_ (1 bit per pixel), or a greyscale _pixmap_ (with 8? 32? bits per pixel)?

Comment: @MtnViewMark: When I say "BGRA" and "32-bit", I mean "full-color with alpha channel" and "32 bits per pixel". Read the question next time.

Comment: @minitech: instead of being rude, you should put some effort into improving your question, since it is still way too vague and you haven't answered all the questions raised in the comments.

Comment: @Paul R: Please explain how the question is vague. (My point is not to be rude - people should really read questions thouroughly before posting comments.)

Comment: How the question is vague: How will you time the code? (Or build it, since you've specified *any* language.) Any OS/hardware restrictions? Do you actually mean BGRA (which would be somewhat unusual), or was that RGBA? Is the input little- or big-endian? What does the fastest code win, if not the 50-pt bounty?

Comment: @minitech: Caleb already beat me to it on most areas where the question is lacking in clarity and definition - I'll just add that you *still* haven't defined how the blur should be applied to the R, G, B and A channels - perhaps you should read the comments more carefully ?

Comment: @Paul R: To quote comment #4: "@Paul R: ***No particular algorithm in mind, as long as it blurs***. Sorry, I should have specified that. @Keith Randall: By "bitmap" I meant "bitmap image, 2-dimensional". ***And yes, blur is "crappy averaging"***, @Peter Taylor. – minitech Jun 11 at 19:38 "

Comment: @Caleb: Yes, I mean BGRA, that is how the input bytes will be ordered. The fastest code gets marked as the answer, and it will be "fastest" as in "run on my computer". I will download & install the latest versions (or other, if specified) of any interpreters or compilers necessary to run/compile the program. If it's not available online, you should provide the compiler/interpreter in your answer.

Comment: Are edges handled by wrapping?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Edges would *ideally* be handled by transparency, but black or white or wrapping all work too.

Answer (score 5):

eTeX, too many chars

```
\immediate\openout5\jobname.out\let\x\newlinechar\x0\catcode0=12\let\y
\linepenalty\def\ndef#1{\expandafter\edef\csname\the#1\endcsname}\loop
\lccode0\x\lowercase{\ndef\x{^^@}}\ifnum\x<255\advance\x1\repeat\def\R
#1 #2 #3 {\Sr#1 \def\Y{#2}\x=0 \Rl#3????}\def\Rle#1\fi#2\Rc{\fi\Rl#1}
\def\Ry#1#2{\ndef{\y;\the\x.#1}{\number`#2 }}\def\Rc#1#2#3#4{\ifnum\Y=
\y\Rle#1#2#3#4\fi\advance\y1 \Ry1#1\Ry2#2\Ry3#3\Ry4#4\Rc}\def\Re{\fi\x
-1\immediate\write5{\Bl1;1.!}\end}\def\Rl#1{\edef\X{\the\x}\advance\x1
\y0 \ifx?#1\Re\fi\Rc#1}\def\Bl#1;{\ifnum\X<#1 \Ble\fi\Bc#1;}\def\Ble
#1!{\fi}\def\Bc#1;#2.{\ifnum\Y<#2 \Bce\fi\By#1;#2.1\By#1;#2.2\By
#1;#2.3\By#1;#2.4\expandafter\Bc\number#1\expandafter;\the\numexpr
#2+1.}\def\Bce#1#2#3;{#1\expandafter\Bl\the\numexpr#3+1;1.}\def\Sr#1
{\x-#1\def~{}\Sl#1 \edef~{\def\noexpand\By####1;####2.####3{\noexpand
\csname\noexpand\the\numexpr(\unexpanded\expandafter{~}+0)/(\unexpanded
{\Bt\X}#1 ####1 *\unexpanded{\Bt\Y}#1 ####2 )\endcsname}}~}\def\Sl#1
{\ifnum#1<\x\else\y-#1 \Sc#1 \advance\x1 \Sl#1 \fi}\def\Sc#1 {\ifnum
#1<\y\else\edef~{\unexpanded\expandafter{~}\unexpanded{\expandafter\t
\csname\the}\numexpr####2+\the\x;\noexpand\the\numexpr####1+\the\y
.####3\endcsname}\advance\y1 \Sc#1 \fi}\def\t#1{\ifx\relax#1\else+#1\fi
}\def\Bt#1#2 #3 {\expandafter\use\the\numexpr(\ifnum#2<#3 1+#2\else
#3\fi+\ifnum\numexpr#2+#3>#1 #1-#3\else#2\fi);}\def\use#1;{#1}
\expandafter\R\noexpand
```

Run as for instance

```
etex filename 10 3 55555555qqqq55555555qqqq5555qqqqqqqq5555qqqqqqqq
```